# Visualization of the *accountable* point-cloud for an anchor

Tags: augmented-reality, azure-spatial-anchors

Everytime creating an ASA, no matter how much time you 'scan' the environment, but only a few seconds after you call 'save' is accoutable, but it's hard to only visualize those point-cloud, and you never know which points are accountable for ASA. Simply visualizaing all point-cloud does not make sense.

So how do we visualize the accountable point-cloud for an anchor? Maybe from ASA there should provide a 'point-cloud visualizer' for this? This might sounds not a big deal but it's very important UX feature to provide proper feedback to the user when creating an anchor. Currently it's very hard to make the anchor creation experience perfect.

Answer (score 0):

As of December 2020, such functionality does not exist in the Azure Spatial Anchors SDK. There is [a feature request for this on the Azure Spatial Anchors feedback site already](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/919252-azure-spatial-anchors/suggestions/41555926-visualizing-the-point-cloud-which-is-accountable-f). The team uses the feedback site to help prioritize its work.

(It looks like this question author, [Cliff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12479238/cliff), created this feature request.)